# Where does HP Fortify put the intermediate files?

Tags: java, fortify

According to the HP Fortify documentation, the Static Code Analyzer first translates the source code into an intermediate format, and then it scans the translated code and generates a vulnerability report.

It says the translation can be done using the following Ant code:

```
<antcall target="compile">
    <param name="build.compiler" value="com.fortify.dev.ant.SCACompiler"/>
</antcall>
```

This will call your "compile" target but force it to use the SCACompiler instead of the regular javac compiler.

I have run Fortify on our Java code and it produces vulnerability reports.  But I do not see the intermediate files anywhere.  I ran a diff between the Java class files that the regular javac compiler produced and the Java class files that the SCACompiler produced, and they were exactly the same.  Are the intermediate files stored somewhere else, or does Fortify automatically delete them after performing the scan?

Comment: Have you tried pausing the process and using a tool like `lsof` with the proper settings to filter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intermediate files are not class or object files. They are NST (Normalized Syntax Tree) files, a proprietary format used by HP Fortify (this is discussed in the book "Secure Programming with Static Analysis". When translating with a build ID, such as:

```
sourceanalyzer -b test ant
```

Then it will be stored in the project working directory. In Windows, typically:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Fortify\sca<version>\build\test
```

or on other platforms:

```
~/.fortify/sca<version>/build/test
```

this will then contain the canonicalized path to the NST, as was performed during the translation. These can then be used to scan multiple times if needed, but should be "cleaned" if scanning a separate new (or updated) codebase.

For ant integration I think it depends on which version of Ant, and the way you are translating, but this way I think it just calls the sourceanalyzer.jar file (which contains the `com.fortify.dev.ant.SCACompiler` class) in order to hook into the JVM and follow the build to create the NST files needed for scanning. I don't believe it's actually a separate version of javac, although perhaps there is a separate version under `<SCA installation directory>/jre/` which it may use.

Answer (score 3):

Lavamunky is correct about the default path for the working directory.  You can change this in  the following locations:

```
1. FortifyInstallRoot\Core\config\fortify.properties: com.fortify.WorkingDirectory
2. FortifyInstallRoot\Core\config\fortify-sca.properties: com.fortify.sca.ProjectRoot
```

Note that you need to use / as the path delimiter instead of \ inside of the config files.  Inside of the folder specified by those paths, the pattern is: sca\build\.

You can also specify these at runtime:

```
sourceanalyzer -b MyBuild -Dcom.fortify.WorkingDirectory=C:\Fortify\Work -Dcom.fortify.sca.ProjectRoot=C:\Fortify\Work
```

The path to the working files would then be:

```
C:\Fortify\Work\sca<version>\build\MyBuild\
```